# Get Raster data in right orientation

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a problem getting raster data in the right orientation. The original raster data when imported into R looks this [image: Original data].

I tried using the transpose function in raster but it didn't work. The transposed data looks like this [image: Transposed].

I used the code below. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Also, is there a way to apply the plausible solution to the entire stack (all rasters are of the same extent)? Thank you.

```
f_PM <- list.files(path=".", 
                   pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)
s_PM <- stack(f_PM) ## create a stack of the rasters
plot(s_PM[[1]]) ##check the orientation
PM <- s_PM[[1]] ## pick one raster and try to change the orientation
PM2 <- t(PM)
plot(PM2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip then transpose:

```
> plot(m)
```

```
> r = t(flip(m))
> plot(r)
```

[image]

Note there's https://gis.stackexchange.com where spatial questions like this get asked. (Too much noise here to help with most spatial stuff).

Comment: Thanks, Spacedman. Is it possible to apply the t(flip(m)) to the raster stack?

Comment: Yes this works for a stack, having its effect on all the layers.